# Selecting attribute of a node in a nested list of items

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have XML of a table of contents. I am generating named .xhtml pages from the list for each anchor point in the XML.

The structure of the TOC contains Chapters, which also list subsections within those chapters. I am trying to dynamically name those subsection anchors using the @href value of the preceding chapter anchor.

Sample XML:

```
<div class="toc" id="s9781483331812.i34"><a class="page" id="pbr-v" title="v"/>
<p class="toc-title">Contents</p>
<ul class="toc">
        <li class="toc-item">
            <a class="ref-chap" href="#s132" id="s35"><b>Preface</b></a>
            <a class="page-ref" href="#pbr-vii" id="s36"><b>vii</b></a>
        </li>
        <li class="toc-item">
            <a class="ref-chap" href="#s135" id="s37"><b>Introduction</b></a>
            <a class="page-ref" href="#pbr-xi" id="s38"><b>xi</b></a>
        </li>
        <li class="toc-item">
            <span class="toc-label" title="1"><b>1.</b></span>
            <a class="ref-chap" href="#s147" id="s39"><b>Chapter</b></a>  
            <a class="page-ref" href="#pbr-1" id="s40"><b>1</b></a>
            <ul class="chapter-section">
                <li class="toc-item"> 
                    <a class="ref-chap" href="#s152" id="s41">Subsection 1</a>  
                    <a class="page-ref" href="#pbr-2" id="s42">2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="toc-item"> 
                    <a class="ref-chap" href="#s158" id="s43">Subsection 2</a>  
                    <a class="page-ref" href="#pbr-6" id="s44">6</a>
                </li>
                <li class="toc-item"> 
                    <a class="ref-chap" href="#s159" id="s45">Subsection 3</a>  
                    <a class="page-ref" href="#pbr-10" id="s46">10</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Sample XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">


<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>        
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[@class='toc']//li[@class='toc-item']">
    <xsl:element name="li">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a[@class='ref-chap']">
    <xsl:element name="a">
        <xsl:attribute name="href" select="concat(substring-after(@href, '#'),'.xhtml')"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template priority="1" match="ul[@class='chapter-section']//a[@class='ref-chap']">
    <xsl:variable name="pagenumber" select="following-sibling::a[@class='page-ref']"/>
    <xsl:element name="a">
        <xsl:attribute name="href" select="concat(substring-after(ancestor::ul[@class='toc']//li[@class='toc-item']//a[@class='ref-chap'][last()]/@href, '#'),'.xhtml','#page',$pagenumber)"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

My desired output is:

```
<div class="toc" id="s9781483331812.i34">
<a class="page" id="pbr-v" title="v"/>
<p class="toc-title">Contents</p>
<ul class="toc">
        <li>
            <a href="s132.xhtml"><b>Preface</b></a>
            <a class="page-ref" href="#pbr-vii" id="s36"><b>vii</b></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="s135.xhtml"><b>Introduction</b></a>
            <a class="page-ref" href="#pbr-xi" id="s38"><b>xi</b></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="toc-label" title="1"><b>1.</b></span>
            <a href="s147.xhtml"><b>Chapter</b></a>  
            <a class="page-ref" href="#pbr-1" id="s40"><b>1</b></a>
            <ul class="chapter-section">
                <li> 
                    <a href="s147.xhtml#page2">Subsection 1</a>  
                    <a class="page-ref" href="#pbr-2" id="s42">2</a>
                </li>
                <li> 
                    <a href="s147.xhtml#page6">Subsection 2</a>  
                    <a class="page-ref" href="#pbr-6" id="s44">6</a>
                </li>
                <li> 
                    <a href="s147.xhtml#page10">Subsection 3</a>  
                    <a class="page-ref" href="#pbr-10" id="s46">10</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I'm getting the error "A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of substring-after() ("#s132", "#s135", ...)". Obviously my XPath is selecting multiple values instead of one. However, I can't figure out how to fix this.

Note: the number of chapter subsections is not known and can vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath expression

```
ancestor::ul[@class='toc']//li[@class='toc-item']//a[@class='ref-chap'][last()]/@href
```

will definitely pick up too much - it will look at all the `ref-chap` anchors inside all the `toc-item` list items within the toc, and give you a sequence consisting of all those anchors that are the last `ref-chap` inside their respective parents.  Since no `toc-item` contains more than one `ref-chap` this means *all* of them.

Given you are currently in the context of a specific `ref-chap`, you don't need to go all the way up to the `toc` level, you only need to go up as far as the nearest `chapter-section` ul element and then pull out that element's nearest preceding sibling `ref-chap`:

```
ancestor::ul[@class='chapter-section'][1]/preceding-sibling::a[@class='ref-chap'][1]/@href
```

Note that since `ancestor::` and `preceding-sibling::` are reverse direction axes, the "nearest" matching item (i.e. the last one in document order) is `[1]`.

Comment: This is great, exactly what I was looking for, but failing to figure out. Thanks for the great explanation as well.